# select data from table where name = list?

Tags: python, mysql

Let's say I have a table names like this :

```
cust_id    cust_name
   1         John
   2         Mary
   3         Pete
```

and I create a list of customers and orders in python like this :

```
{'Pete','pen','Mary','apple','Pete','pencil','John','shirt','John','watch','Mary','sandal'}
```

how do I get the `cust_id` from the table above where the name is like on the list so that a new table will be like this?

```
id_order    cust_id    orders  
   1           3        pen
   2           2       apple
   3           3       pencil
   4           1       shirt
   5           1       watch
   6           2       sandal
```

so the main point of my question how do i select `cust_id` in the order of my python customer list? and insert them to a new table of order above?

Comment: Do you want an SQL query as an answer? I don't understand what Python has got to do with the question, to be honest.

Comment: What kind of data structure is your data in?  Are you using a relational database?  What library are you using to interact with it?

Comment: Please elaborate your question, so it will be easy for all to help.

Comment: You mean `... WHERE cust_name IN ('Pete', 'Mary', 'John')` ?

Comment: yes..
i don't know the sql query to get cust_id where the cust_name is "in the python list"

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming all the required columns are already present in your current table say `MY_TABLE`. Your SQL query should be like:

```
SELECT id_order, cust_id, orders from  MY_TABLE where cust_name IN ('Pete', 'Mary', 'John');
```

Columns I am expecting in "MY_TABLE":

- id_order
- cust_id
- orders
- cust_name